# Problem with Document expired after pressing "back button" in browser

Tags: javascript, php, back-button

We are using an e-commerce script, which is coded with ionCube technology. In the product catalog we have filters. They are sent via post method. Because of the script I cannot use get - even if I want to.
When the user will try to go to a product details, by choosing one of the filtered products in the catalog, when he tries to go back via back button in browser, he gets Document expired. After clicking the refresh button it shows the right catalog page with all filters which were chosen.

We tried to set this on server:
ini_set('session.cache_limiter','public');
It helps with the above problem, but it corrupts the cart page - everything goes crazy.

I tried many scripts founded in Stack Overflow and in other places on the net, but it won't work.

Please notice that I also cannot use PHP, because of ionCube. When I am trying to add anything in the index.php I get a corrupt notice after the page reload.

Any solution?

Comment: You're unlikely to be able to fix this without access to the source code. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get is the solution, but the script has to be coded that way.

Comment: @ceejayoz Is there any option to force the refresh after using the back button in the browser?

Comment: Not if you can't edit the code.